# java how to ensure that all variables have been initialized error in a while loop The local variable may not have been initialized

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a program that reads from a txt file line by line splits up the string and puts it in to an arraylist

```
while ((inputLine2 = infile2.readLine() )!= null)
{

    //string to split up
    String[] programData = inputLine2.split(":");
    List<CoursesInProgram> programContents = new ArrayList(programContents);
    //constructor

      programContents.add(new CoursesInProgram(programData[2],programData[3],
            programData[4],programData[5],programData[6],programData[7],
            programData[8],programData[9]));
    //other constructor
    programlist.add
    (new Program(programData[0],programData[1], programContents));        

}
```

And I get the error `The local variable programContents may not have been initialized.`  Reading here I learned that happens when eclipse thinks that it possible i'll never enter the loop.

so I changed it to a do while loop and still had the same problem.
then i tried to initialize the array outside the loop and i got a duplicate variable error.

what do you think is the solution?

Comment: `List<CoursesInProgram> programContents = new ArrayList(programContents)`: the variable `programContents` appears twice here; what do you expect to happen?

Comment: took me a while but your comment was enough for me to figure out the problem. This is what happens when you're still coding at 3 in the morning after 12 hours straight.  thanks for your help.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth
Your comment was what caused me to figure out my error but I don't think I can accept a comment as an answer. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<CoursesInProgram> programContents = new ArrayList(programContents)`: the variable `programContents` appears twice here; what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
List<CoursesInProgram> programContents = new ArrayList();

while (...) {
    ...
    programContents = new ArrayList(programContents);
```